# How to apply jQuery on dynamicky inserted html

Tags: jquery

Here is the code, as an example of my problem:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){    
         $("#temp").click(function(){       
           $("#temp").hide();            
         });

        $("#butt").click(function(){  
             $("#result").html("<div id=temp>Click to hide</div>")    
        });    
     });    
     </script>

     <button id=butt>Show text</button>
     <div id=result><!-- here goes generated html --> </div>
```

Question: why `$("#temp").click(function(){..})` can't bee applied on newly generated html?

When I run this script, clicking on button, I get inserted code to

```
div *id=result*,
```

however, although the newly inserted code is

```
<div id=temp>test</div>
```

it is be possible to control this element by function

```
$("#temp").click(function(){..})
```

So why is that? Why it is not possible to apply early defined functions on lately inserted html?

Comment: if you had used the title in [google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=How+to+apply+jQuery+on+dynamically+inserted+html&spell=1)

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1672vv/)

```
    $("#butt").click(function(){  
         $("#result").html("<div id=temp>Click to hide</div>") ;
           $("#temp").click(function(){       
           $("#temp").hide();            
     });
    });
```